# How to create forest plots of subgroups by treatment (ggforest)

Tags: r

I am trying to create forest plots that look at the impact of certain covariates on survival between 2 treatment arms. ggforest allows for adding factors, but it compares the between the factors themselves and not how the factors impact treatment. For example, patients could have received either drug A or drug B which is the TREATMENT. I want to build a forest plot that looks at if SEX and RACE were subgroups where Drug A or drug B were better.

I've already tried adding factors as below, but these only look at the impact of the factors regardless of treatment (drug A vs drug B) when I want to look at how the factors influence the response to A vs B.

```
model <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ TREATMENT + SEX + RACE, data = pancreatic)

ggforest(model)
```

Comment: You may want to interact factors with treatment. Nonetheless, asking about modeling questions is off-topic on StackOverflow as there is no coding question. See [Stats.StackExchange.com](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) or [DataScience.StackExchange.com](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).