# Forest Plot for Cox Regression stratified by Treatment Effect on a subgroup

Tags: r, survival-analysis, r-forestplot

relative novice to R here.
I am looking to plot treatment effect by subgroup. I believe this was asked before, but without response ([How to create forest plots of subgroups by treatment (ggforest)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56844162/how-to-create-forest-plots-of-subgroups-by-treatment-ggforest))

So for example, using the 'colon' dataset, in the below code sex and rx are treated as separate predictors for status.

```
require("survival")
library(survminer)
model <- coxph( Surv(time, status) ~ sex + rx + adhere,
                data = colon )
ggforest(model)
```

However, I would like to see if there are different effects of **rx** on **status** stratified by **sex**.

Meaning, I would like to generate a forest plot where for **female** and for **male** sex, there will be three plots each - one for each treatment arm.

Simply adding an interaction term does not seem to make any difference.

I tried instead to create an indicator variable instead, but this didn't seem to help either.

```
library(tidyverse)
colon <- colon %>% 
  mutate(indicator = factor(case_when(sex==0 & rx=="Obs" ~ "Female-Obs",
                               sex==0 & rx=="Lev" ~ "Female-Lev",
                               sex==0 & rx=="Lev+5FU" ~ "Female-FU",
                               sex==1 & rx=="Obs" ~ "Male-Obs",
                               sex==1 & rx=="Lev" ~ "Male-Lev",
                               sex==1 & rx=="Lev+5FU" ~ "Male-FU"), levels=c("Female-Obs", "Female-Lev", "Female-FU", "Male-Obs", "Male-Lev", "Male-FU")))

model <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ indicator, data=colon)
ggforest(model)
```

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: 'Error in ggforest(model) : could not find function "ggforest"'

Comment: Oh so sorry! It's in library(survminer)!
I updated the code example above to reflect this!